# Windows Phone Scroll Viewer not scrolling

Tags: windows-phone, scrollviewer, stackpanel

My StackPanel which is inside a ScrollViewer isn't scrolling for some reason.

Code:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="478" Name="scrollerButtons" Width="Auto" Canvas.Left="668" Canvas.Top="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanelButtons" Orientation="Vertical" Canvas.Left="162" Canvas.Top="43" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto">
            <Image Height="60" Name="imgA" Source="Images/a.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60" Tap="imgA_Tap"></Image>
            <Image Height="60" Name="imgB" Source="Images/b.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60" Tap="imgB_Tap"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You've set the vertical scroll to disabled in the ScrollViewer?

Comment: Oh my god -_-' I should shoot myself, twice... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Added an answer, but you can remove the question if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` from Disabled to Auto.